# Does Oracle's Application Continuity Works only with RAC implementations?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, replay, continuity

Does Oracle's Application Continuity Works only with RAC implementations or can Also Work for single oracle instance.

I am trying to implement Application continuity for an Oracle db based application which does not have RAC, there is only one oracle DB instance. 
My question here is, will AC works without RAC.

Comment: It will be very difficult to answer your questions since you have put three of them into a single one. I propose you close this question and start three new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AC will work as long as you can define a service with the correct set of attributes:

- FAILOVER_TYPE : Set this to TRANSACTION
- COMMIT_OUTCOME : Set this to TRUE

You don't need to have a multi-instance RAC database. You can have a single instance database on your primary site and ADG on the secondary site for example.